# Azure Pipeline - Why parameter value is required

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hi have a pipeline with the below parameter in the .yaml file:

```
parameters:
- name: Proceed
   displayName: Should we proceed
   type: boolean
   default: Yes
- name: Description
   displayName: Short description
   type: string

trigger: none

stages:
- template: sometemplate.yaml
  parameters:
    Proceed: ${{ parameters.Proceed }}
    CopySomething: ${{ parameters.Description }}
```

When I run the pipeline, the "Description" appears to be required even thought is not specified in the parameter.  It is asking me to enter a value.  I need this to be a non-required parameter and yet don't have to be set to a default value?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why parameter value is required

For this issue, currently this is by design: "# default value; if no default, then the parameter **MUST be given by the user at runtime**"

[image]

You can refer the [document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/runtime-parameters.md#syntax) on github. As a workaround, agree with Krzysztof Madej, you need to set default value `''`.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your only option is default value `' '` like here:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: Proceed
  displayName: Should we proceed
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: Description
  displayName: Short description
  type: string
  default: ' '

trigger: none
pr: none

stages:
- template: sometemplate.yaml
  parameters:
    Proceed: ${{ parameters.Proceed }}
    CopySomething: ${{ parameters.Description }}
```

Be aware that `yes` is not valid value for boolean type.

Comment: Providing value as default space seems to work, but please notice that if end-user starts to write that string - he might preserve that space value, resulting in further problems. One approach could be just to use $param.Trim(" ") function in ps1 script - then extra spaces will be removed.

Comment: An empty string - `default: ''` - also does the trick.